# How can I printf the series of the following series of fraction Sn=1/n+1/(n-1)+1/(n-2)+...+1 in c programming?

Tags: c

How can I printf the series of the following series of fraction Sn=1/n+1/(n-1)+1/(n-2)+...+1 in c programming?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    //declaring integer variables
    int i,num; 
    //declaring float variable
    float sum = 0; 
    printf("Enter any number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    //creating for loop 
    for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) //
    {
        sum = sum + 1/i + 1/i-1;
        if(i==num)
        {
            printf("1/%d=", i);
        }else
        {
            printf(" 1/%d +", i);
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of the series are: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: `1/i` will always be `0` because it's doing integer arithmetic. Use `1.0/i`

Comment: `1/i-1` should be `1.0/(i-1)`

Comment: `1.0/(i-1)` for first iteration cannot work

Comment: You don't need to add both `1/i` and `1/i-1` in each iteration.

Comment: Just add `1.0/i` in each iteration, counting down from `n` to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Sn=1/n+1/(n-1)+1/(n-2)+...+1 */

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned n = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 10;
        float sum = 1.0;
        if( n ){
                printf("S(%d) = ", n);
                for( ; n > 1; n-- ){
                        sum += 1.0/n;
                        printf("1/%d + ", n);
                }
                printf("1 =~ %f\n", sum);
        }
}
```

Comment: `strtoul()` makes more sense than `strtol()` with `unsigned`.  Perhaps even `unsigned long` too?